# Publishing Fails

Tags: wpf, browser, publish

**Tool:** Microsoft Visual studio 2008
**Project Type:** WPF Browser application

When after rebuidling all,project is published. it fails with followiung error.

Cannot publish because a project failed to build.
Could not find file 'obj\Release*.exe'.

Clean and rebuild All has been done, no positive signs.
System has been restarted, no positive sign.

Needs help.

Regards,
Shah

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by changing machine.

Same project is working on new machine.

Regards,
Shah